# Php set_cookie SOMETIMES doesn't works

Tags: php, cookies

i am using a cookie to remember the language visitors choose.
Here is the beginning of my lang.php page.

```
<?php
$time=microtime();
if (isset($_GET['lg']) AND ($_GET['lg'] != NULL)) {
    if ($_GET['lg'] == 'fr') {
        setcookie("userlang", "fr", time()*60*60*24*30);
        header("location: index.php");
    }
    elseif ($_GET['lg'] == 'en') {
        setcookie("userlang", "en", time()*60*60*24*30);
        header("location: index.php");
    }
    else {
        header("location: lang.php");
    }
}
else {
    if (isset($_COOKIE['userlang'])) {
        unset($_COOKIE['userlang']);
        setcookie("userlang", '', time()-3600);
    }
}
?>
```

its the top of the page, nothing before that for sure.
Sometimes it works, and sometimes it just reload the page as if no cookies were set... and i can click on the flag of the language i choose many times.. same...
I then stop, wait some minutes, and when i choose a language, suddently it works....
please help me! =)

Any idea maybe from leet coders?

thanks in advance.

Comment: You're also setting ridiculously large and strange cookie expiration times. Most likely, you want `time() + 60*60*24*30`, not multiple time.

Comment: Why don't you use `session` instead of cookies? Not a problem in the script shown but generally, the script doesn't stop without `exit;` upon location header.

Comment: so with set_cookie i need an "exit;" after the "header()"?

Answer (score 2):

to set cookie:

```
setcookie("myCookie", "cookie_data", time()+3600);
```

in you code you missed + sign with time.
it should be

```
setcookie("userlang", "fr", time()+60*60*24*30);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem... I found the soliution: domain name with www and without www creates different cookies. so if user creates cookie in domain without www, after some time try to change it, but in domain with www it don't changes. it takes cookie witch was created in domain without www.

Answer (score 0):

```
setcookie("userlang", "fr", time()+60*60*24*30);
```

its not `setcookie("userlang", "fr", time()*60*60*24*30);`

Comment: i changed that following philag's comment upper, thanks, can the error comes from that mistake? Because it usualy worked... except sometimes.... strange i have to say.